# Cannot create a Dataproc cluster when setting the fs.defaultFS property?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

This was already the object of discussion in previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248139/insufficient-number-of-datanodes-reporting-when-creating-dataproc-cluster), however, I'm not convinced with the answers as the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1) specify that it is possible to create a cluster setting the fs.defaultFS property. Moreover, even if possible to set this property programmatically, sometimes, it's more convenient to set it from command line.

So I wanted to know why the following option when passed to my cluster creation command does not work: `--properties core:fs.defaultFS=gs://my-bucket`?  Please note I haven't included all parameters as I ran the command without the previous flag and it succeeded to create the cluster. However, when passing this, I get: "failed: Cannot start master: Insufficientnumber of DataNodes reporting."

If anyone managed to create a dataproc cluster by setting the fs.defaultFS that'd be great? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true there are still known issues due to certain dependencies on actual HDFS; the docs were not intended to imply that setting fs.defaultFS to a GCS path at cluster-creation time would work, but to simply provide a convenient example of a property that appears in `core-site.xml`; in theory it would work to set `fs.defaultFS` to a *different* preexisting HDFS cluster, for example. I've filed a ticket to change the example in the documentation to avoid confusion.

Two options:

1. Just override `fs.defaultFS` at job-submission time using per-job properties
2. Workaround some of the known issues by setting `fs.defaultFS` explicitly using an initialization action instead of cluster properties.

Option 1 is better understood to work because cluster-level HDFS dependencies won't change. Option 2 works because most of the incompatibilities occur during initial startup only, and initialization actions run after the relevant daemons start up already. To override the setting in an init action, you'd use `bdconfig`:

```
bdconfig set_property \
    --name 'fs.defaultFS' \
    --value 'gs://my-bucket' \
    --configuration_file /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml \
    --clobber
```

Comment: Great, so I tried this and it's correctly setting that field with cluster creation success. However, when submitting a spark job, I get the following exception: "vysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------;'".  I'd like to know if there are other config to change along this one? I suspect that when fs.defaultFS is set at this level, the job tries to read the settings file from gs://my-bucket/etc/hive/conf/"vysettings.xml. So not sure it's good to do that at submit?

Comment: Yeah, there can be lots of further assumptions baked into frameworks that cause problems; the GCS posix permissions are "fake" since access is actually controlled by IAM permissions, so you can set `fs.gs.reported.permissions` to whatever you want it to report, either at cluster creation time `core:fs.gs.reported.permissions=777`, or if it's at Spark job-submission time you might need to use the "spark.hadoop." prefix: `--properties spark.hadoop.fs.gs.reported.permissions=777`

Comment: Here's where that config key is defined in code: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/fs/gcs/GoogleHadoopFileSystemConfiguration.java#L66

Comment: This works! However, after experimenting, I'd recommend the approach to set `fs.defaultFS` from the code as it requires minimum changes, moreover, it's possible to get the Dataproc bucket from the `fs.gs.system.bucket` config.

Comment: one last thing I wanted to know about this approach of modifying `fs.defaultFS` is that in principle, the spark job should be less performant when pointing it to gs:// as writing temporary to hdfs is done in the cluster, so it's faster. However, Google keep promoting that its network is the best so I assume that the performance bottleneck assumption is shadowed by the quality of Google network, hence performance between Dataproc cluster and Cloud storage shouldn't decrease vs Dataproc writing/reading to hdfs?

Comment: It would depend on the workload. GCS can indeed achieve even better throughput than HDFS because the network traffic could be striping across a large number of physical disks, but small round-trip latency is worse on GCS because it fundamentally goes through extra layers (auth, routing, SSL/TLS). In general, you probably don't have to worry about performance differences, and typical Spark jobs processing large amounts of data should do well on GCS due to being throughput-bound, but if you want to squeeze out every percent of efficiency  you would need to think about workload-specific aspects.