# Dataproc creation fails when updating fs.defaltFS using --properties

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I created a dataproc with defaultFS as hdfs.that is working fine.But whenever i try to update fs.defaultFS to 'gs' the dataproc dashboard showing an error "Unable to Start Master, Insufficient number of datanodes reporting."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot create a Dataproc cluster when setting the fs.defaultFS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775339/cannot-create-a-dataproc-cluster-when-setting-the-fs-defaultfs-property)

Comment: You can find the answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775339/cannot-create-a-dataproc-cluster-when-setting-the-fs-defaultfs-property).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this question is a duplicate of [Cannot create a Dataproc cluster when setting the fs.defaultFS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775339/cannot-create-a-dataproc-cluster-when-setting-the-fs-defaultfs-property)

Re-pasting here for easier readability/discoverability vs just putting it in the comment thread.